# Where are the various Krosmaster Arena tokens supposed to go?

Tags: krosmaster-arena

In the Krosmaster Arena board game box, there are a variety of tokens that come with the set. In the plastic "piece container", the eight original figures are already set in place, and there's an obvious spot for the eight character cards.

There are four other cardboard punch outs, and included on those are a large amount of tokens. Are those designed to go into a specific location in the plastic container? If so, where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your looking at the box with the token slots closest to you. Figs on the far side. From left to right its: dice, bag of (mp/ap/damage/coins), demonic rewards(gold and 1/2 of granite), demonic rewards (jade and 1/2 granite) (each slot holds 1&1/2 colors), round tokens(mobs,traps,bombs), gg tokens,
The character cards have an obvious spot in the bottom and the terrain stacks on top.